# Keyboard not closing when dismiss the dialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment which i use to show map. From this fragment I am opening another dialog fragment which have an editText. On clicking editText the keyboard opens but when I dismiss the dialogFragment without first closing the keyboard, the dialogFragment closes as it should but the keyboard remains open. and after again touching anywhere the keyboard closes. How do I close the keyboard on dismissing the dialogFragment.

I have already tried : 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` in activity.

also tried :

```
InputMethodManager imm =
                (InputMethodManager) messageEditTxt.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm.isActive())
            imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

in onDismiss function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Context context, View view) {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
                    (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(
                            Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                    view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity(), getView())
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that it is related to the windowSoftInput defined in the manifest. After removing `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` from the activity, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just place this in your global class and you can access anywhere

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(activity);
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

for Activity-:

```
GlobalClass.hideSoftKeyborad(MainActivity.this);
```

for fragments-

```
GlobalClass.hideSoftKeyborad(getActivity);
```

Comment: already tried not working......i passed the activity context and all but no solution.